# Elastic Search - check if array of strings has any string that starts with word "cake"

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

These are my fields:

```
      {"brand" : "A",
      "productType" : "food",
      "infoList" : [
        "pizza-34","cake-qaw-34"
      ]},
      {
       "brand" : "B",
      "productType" : "food",
      "infoList" : [
        "pasta-3"
      ]}
```

I want only those documents to be returned which begin with the word "cake" anywhere in their infoList. In this case, I should get this

```
{"brand" : "A",
          "productType" : "food",
          "infoList" : [
            "pizza-34","cake-qaw-34"
          ]}
```

Can someone tell how to achieve this?
PS: Cannot use regexp for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) to get those documents whose array of strings has any string that starts with the word “cake”

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "infoList": "cake"
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67778291",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "brand": "A",
          "productType": "food",
          "infoList": [
            "pizza-34",
            "cake-qaw-34"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "prefix": {
          "infoList": "cake"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67778291",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "brand": "B",
          "productType": "food",
          "infoList": [
            "pasta-3"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Yes @Meg, you can use the `must_not` clause along with the prefix query. Please go through the updated part of the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help! I meant to ask that how to get documents that have all documents other than cake. It can contain cake also. eg: 
 {"brand" : "A",
      "productType" : "food",
      "infoList" : [
        "pizza-34","cake-qaw-34"
      ]},
      {
       "brand" : "B",
      "productType" : "food",
      "infoList" : [
        "pasta-3", "cake-45"
      ]}
Both of these should be returned because they both have words other than cake. If there is no cake, then also it should be returned

Comment: @Meg may I know why you have unaccepted the answer ?

Comment: can you please help me in the above scenario as well